# Program not Painting

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I intended for this to paint a square on my JPanel, however, it does not show up.
What am I doing wrong?

```
class GUI extends JPanel {
    private static Game game = new Game();
    ...
    public GUI () {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setAttributes();
                makeMenu();
            }
        });
    }
    ... 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit: the code**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class GUI extends JPanel {
    private static Game game = new Game();

    private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final private static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
    final private static int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
    //Board size 25x25px
    final private static int PIXEL_SIZE = 20;
    public GUI () {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            setAttributes();
            makeMenu();
         }
      });
    }
    public static void setAttributes() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("");
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void makeMenu() {
        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                game.startGame();
            }
        });
        panel.add(start);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
    }
    public void setGameFrame() {
        panel.removeAll();
        frame.setTitle("Snake v0.1");
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.white);
      g.drawRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
   }
    public void paintGraphics() {
        int[][] pixels = Game.getGraphics();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code shows nothing wrong per se, but doesn't show much either. Thus your error likely lies elsewhere in code not shown. Time to do some debugging. I do have to wonder about your static Game variable game (static??), and your calling invokeLater from within a JPanel's constructor which is quite strange as this constructor should only be called on the EDT, so why the queuing of a Runnable on the EDT there? Suggestion: create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Let us really see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Here's the full GUI class: http://pastebin.com/5tDRvwL6 - And I'm new to Java, so I am probably doing a bunch of things wrong.

Comment: No, please do not do this, do not post code in a link. You should debug, you should put in the effort to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org), and you should post your code here with your question, not in a link. Please, we're volunteers, so the effort should be yours, not ours.

Comment: I posted it because I know it's an obvious error, that does not need debugging.

Comment: `"I posted it because I know it's an obvious error, that does not need debugging."` -- no... if it were obvious, you'd post code that showed the error, right? You didn't, so it's obviously not so obvious. By debugging, I meant doing some work to isolate the error. This could be done with println statements. For instance if this were my error, and I didn't know what was causing it, I'd put println's everywhere, and I'd quickly see that the paintComponent method isn't even being called.

Comment: I didn't know where the error was, I knew that it was an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your code. Where do you ever add GUI to anything? Answer: you don't, and if you don't, nothing will be painted. Solution: add it to the gui, and read the tutorials as there is much to fix in your code.

Other suggestions:

- Get rid of all static variables except for the contants.
- Call your invokeLater in your main method, not in a JPanel's constructor
- Again, add your painting GUI to your actual gui so that it gets added to something that will display it.
- Don't call `getGraphics()` on any component as that will get you a non-persisting Graphics object.

---

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class GUI extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 200;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final int RECT_X = 20;
   private static final int RECT_Y = RECT_X;
   private static final int RECT_WIDTH = 100;

   public GUI() {
      setBackground(Color.darkGray);
   }

   // use @Override to be sure that your method is a true override
   // Note that paintComponent should be protected, not public
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.white);

      // avoiding "magic" numbers here.
      g.fillRect(RECT_X, RECT_Y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_WIDTH);
      g.setColor(Color.red);
      g.drawRect(RECT_X, RECT_Y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_WIDTH);
   }

   // so that the layout managers know how big I want this JPanel to be.
   // this is a dumb method implementation. Yours will hopefully be smarter
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H); 
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      GUI mainPanel = new GUI();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please link me? I'm failing to find a tutorial that shows how to "add" it.

Comment: @ModifyYou: you add it by calling `someComponent.add(thisComponent)`. That someComponent must be a JPanel or other component whose component hierarchy eventually leads to a top-level window, here your JFrame. The Swing tutorials can be found here: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). Search on the page for `Swing`.

Comment: What exactly do I pass in the parameter?

Comment: @ModifyYou: It's up to you -- where do you want to put this JPanel?

Comment: @ModifyYou: for example, see edit above. In the example, I add the current JPanel to the JFrame's contentPane. But what you add your JPanel to will all depend on how you plan to use it. That's up to you.